# Error When Querying For A Substring Using Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to use dynamic linq to obtain a subset of people from a database using Entity
Framework (EF). I'm running into a problem when using the contains operation. Here is the entity
for the People table:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a query that works successfully.

```
var people = personContext
    .People
    .OrderBy("id asc")
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

Notice that I'm using dynamic linq in the OrderBy method. However, when I try to apply
filtering, I get an exception.

```
var people = personContext
    .People
    .Where("id.Contains(15)")
    .OrderBy("id asc")
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

What I'd like to get back is a subset of people with ids that contain the substring "15", such as:

```
"015", "115", "151", "152", etc.
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error.

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException was unhandled by user code
    Message=No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'String'
```

What is the syntax for determining if the Id field contains the string "15"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the syntax for determining if the Id field contains the string "15"?

Well, definitely not `.Where("id.Contains(15)")` which is trying to invoke the method `Contains` with **numeric** value 15.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions), you can use either a *string literal*:

```
.Where("id.Contains(\"15\")")
```

or [substitution values](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#_Substitution_Values):

```
.Where("id.Contains(@0)", "15")
```

Comment: I was missing the quotes! Since I am comparing strings, the quotes are required. Nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

I feel misconception here... You are not supposed to use LINQ like this. 
As a start you need to invoke the overloads that accept lambdas; then you specify the property in the lambda and if its a string you invoke `Contains` on it. Like so:

```
var people = personContext
    .People
    .Where(p => p.Id.Contains("15"))
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
    .Skip(0) // You don't need this line.
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

The EF itself will do the heavy lifting and translate these pure C# codes into the correct SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **Contains** in the LINQ query. Instead you can try this

```
var people = (from p in personContext.Set<People>() 
    where p.Id.Contains("15")
    orderby p.Id
    select p).Skip(0).Take(5).ToList();
```